# Deploying a standalone Ember app - rewrite config for the API layer

Tags: symfony, mod-rewrite, ember.js

I have a standalone Ember application and a Symfony API that I need to deploy. The Ember app is built with grunt, so I have a standalone HTML file and Javascript that needs to be served.

Originally I tried using the Alias direction but it didn't work the way I expected it to. I've done rewrite rules before but nothing quite like this.

So far I can get everything to route to the Ember app, but no go on catching the API calls to route them properly to the Symfony app.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site/back-end/web  # Symfony app
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html#$1 [L]

    # Rewrite directives here
    # map /api to Symfony - /var/www/html/site/back-end/web
    # map / to Ember - /var/www/html/site/front-end/dist/index.html
    # anything not /api needs to route to the Ember

</VirtualHost>
```

Any tips on the config here?

Comment: How did you solve this finally? I am facing the same issue and can't get my head around it. I also thought about having a "frontend" bundle", I also need to deploy the whole server from one repository.

Comment: @m0c I would keep your Ember code *out* of your backend repo. We use a separate git repo altogether now. Treat it like an iOS app for your backend.